# How to set up phpmyadmin in localhost?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, wampserver

Im new to php so please explain how to set up wamp amd xampp and get access to phpmyadmin?

Comment: Find some tutorial on youtube that can help you. There are a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

start xampp or wampp and go to browser and enter the URL like this
`localhost/phpmyadmin`

Comment: 404 not found ....The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Comment: have you started the apache and mysql in XAMPP control panel

Answer (score 0):

### Install xampp or wamp and it well setup automatically :

in wamp :

install :  https : //make. wordpress .org/ core/handbook/tutorials/installing-a-local-server/wampserver/

you can access phpmyadmin by following this
[Wamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCZtB.png)

---

in xampp :

install : http : //www. wikihow. com/Install-XAMPP-for-Windows

you can access phpmyadmin by following this 
[xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nL3d.png)

Comment: delete spaces in the Links before using it